# Solved Mounting a drive in my home directory at boot

Tags: partitioning, mount, home-directory

So I installed Ubuntu 17.10 on a Lenovo 15IYB and got a new shiny SSD already setup to increase my user storage.

as of right now I am also dual booting (i really wish I would not have to) so I split the new drive to contain the swap, the exchange partition, and my personal data partition... at this point, all is fine and dandy.

the exchange drive is ok I don't have any problem with it.

the problem is I cannot mount my personal drive to have write access by any means ... like even on root (using sudo on a file-browser cannot write any data or even mount it)

Manual mounting is not working. I tried for a few hours, not this solution https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/170641/how-can-i-mount-a-drive-under-my-home-directory-at-boot

all I could do is mount the drive in or.... pretty useless in my case since even root has it on to

at this point, I am just clueless. I want the drive to be in my home partition but I don't care if it is using a symlink at this point. I just want to be able to write data to the drive at this point...

the file system is ext4, I need to be able to execute files from there.

also, my new swap is not doing anything unlike with the old drive I had ... must be something wrong there too.

for information here is the current `fstab` I have

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sdb3 during installation
UUID=ac67a85e-0a13-495c-8c9e-db340f7dc45b /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda3 during installation
#UUID=86cee994-0846-40e3-9eac-105f17b3bc25 none            swap    sw              0       0
#New swap on crucial
UUID=ae53f536-5bed-4e22-a220-7c685a5f597c none            swap    sw              0       0
# Exchange Partition (acessible thru windows)
UUID=27DEEA4B402D1DB0  /media/Exchange  ntfs-3g  auto,users,uid=1000,gid=100,dmask=027,fmask=137,utf8,rw  0  0
# Personal Partition (Data storage parttition
UUID=210010cc-4768-415e-94aa-3aafbc325ff2  /home/spark/Personal  ext4  rw,noauto,user,sync,exec   0  2
```

any idea on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: was the drive properly dismounted in windows? Note: windows fast start is a hibernation. Hibernated drives will mount read only to prevent file corruption.

Comment: try mounting to a location other than /home/$USER/, ie. try using a /mnt/personal, /personal or even /home/personal (assuming no user has that name)

Comment: the drive was not touched by windows .... mounting the drive in /media/personal result in the drive being in readonly...
trying to open the drive from a filebroser result in an error saying I do not have the permission to perform the action.... same if I go into root

Comment: Edit: root had to the drive ... it just did not let me acess it for some strange reason,  I took ownship of the drive and made a symlink to it

Comment: Please don't mark a post "[Solved]". Instead, answer your question below (if someone else didn't answer it) and click the check mark to the left of the answer that worked for you to mark things solved.

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include the output of `sudo mount -t ext4 -U 210010cc-4768-415e-94aa-3aafbc325ff2 /home/spark/Personal` and `ls -ld /home/spark/Personal`? Thanks.